# How to see a webservice's raw request

Tags: c#, web-services, fiddler

in a standard .NET webservice (lie the basic sample "hello word" one created by VisualStudio), how can I access the raw call coming from a client? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean an old-style ASMX web service (now considered "Legacy technology" by Microsoft), or a WCF Web Service?

Answer (score 4):

I'd try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy in WS client

http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox you can view requests and response with Firebug, I like fiddle as well.

Comment: What you do in your spare time is your business my friend

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Request` contains the information of the incoming request.